# How to get marker in handler google maps web API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make an action dependent on what marker has been clicked.  But in event handler argument no field that named feature.

```
marker.addListener('click', function (event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        // feature is undefined
    });
```

I am creating markers and adding their listeners in loop so it is hard to make different handler functions.

So how to get marker that clicked in event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` inside the click event function is the marker that was clicked (for `google.maps.Marker` objects)

```
marker.addListener('click', function (event) {
    var feature = this.feature;
});
```